# How to create a diff of a file between it's current and the latest tagged version in bzr?

Tags: python, bazaar

I have a file that is tracked using bzr, and I'd like to script the creation of a diff between it's current (current as in current, not latest commited), and latest commited version *that is tagged*.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Not much of a bzr scripting or a Python expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import commands
import sys
import os

# Get the revision number of the most recent tagged commit.
tags = commands.getoutput("bzr tags --sort=time")
latest = tags.split()[-1]

target = sys.argv[-1]
if not os.path.isfile(target):
    print "Error, no such file: '"+target+"'"
    sys.exit(1)

print commands.getoutput("bzr diff "+target+" -r "+latest)
```

Usage:

```
 python diff-from-tagged.py test
```

Output:

```
=== modified file 'test'
--- test    2011-01-08 19:20:31 +0000
+++ test    2011-01-08 20:00:12 +0000
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 dfsafd
+The quick brown fox
```

Comment: Thanks much. Here's also the Lua version I came up with (but forgot to update the question. More helps)

<code>
local f = assert(io.popen("bzr tags --sort=time | tail -1", 'r'))
local s = assert(f:read('*a'))
f:close()
tagname = string.match(s, "^([^ ]+)")
assert(tagname)
os.execute(string.format([[bzr diff -r tag:%s "myfile" > 'changes']], tagname))</code>

Comment: @Vadi -- yow.  Why don't you add that to your question anyway, so you can format it with <code> tags?  :)